# Passing DAE File to OpenGL ES on iPhone - Handling Tangents and Binormals - Maya

Tags: iphone, objective-c, opengl-es, maya

I am working on parsing a Maya DAE file into OpenGL ES on the iphone. I have noticed that in the DAE file, in addition to the usual vertices, normals and texture co-ords, that there is something called "Tangents" and "Binormals".

Does anyone know how I should handle these within OpenGL ES V1.1 ? Are they values that I can ignore or should I be passing somehow to the OpenGL ES engine ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you are planning to do with your DAE file.

Normal, Tangent and Binormal are the three versors of the [Frenet frame](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_geometry_of_curves). 
They give information about the surface the vertex is on.

I think, for a simplified use, you can just store the normal and skip the rest.